# making an IF statement using items from a expandablelistview in another class

Tags: java, android, class, if-statement, android-youtube-api

First of all i have an application with an expandablelistview, so far everything woks, but what i want to do is when every child in each parent is clicked a new YouTube video is opened, i know how to do this but the problem is that there are A LOT of items in each list and each item/child plays its own video.

Is there a way for me to just do an IF statement inside the onInitializationSuccess method where it takes a item from the array created depending on which child was clicked on the Expandable list class i have.

```
public class Videos extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "wqafesf968se15fes6fe...";
    static private final String VIDEO = "MveeQaTefwaewRE";

    public final String VideoList[]={"MvJT5E","LKKdpJU"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videos);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }



@Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
                YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
            // IF statement here with an item from the array depending on which child was clicked
player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
        }

    }
```

Here is the onClick method which is in ANOTHER class which that extends Activity

```
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        final String selected = (String) listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, 1);                

        switch (groupPosition) {
        case 0:
            switch (childPosition) {
            case 0:
                Intent adobeEFintro = new Intent("com.program.STUFF"); 
                startActivity(adobeEFintro);
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct an array of URLS in the class containing the onClick method which passes the URL directly to the Video class. This is explained in
[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Video.class);
intent.putExtra("URL", <insertUrlHere>);
startActivity(intent)
```

In the Video activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("URL");
}
```

Comment: can you please provide an example

Comment: PS. the Onclick methos is in ANOTHER class

Comment: Is the other class an adapter? Are you opening the Videos class from the onClick ?

Comment: the other class creates the expandablelistview, mit creates the parent and childen, the onClick opens the videos Class

Comment: Can you create an array of the video URLS in onClick listener and get the associated URL when an child is clicked? You could then pass the URL in the intent to the Video class.

Comment: how to i pass the URL in the intent to the video class, i thought intent only took a string like "com.program.stuff" and no other parameter.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example and some more information.

Comment: This is fine, now how to i access this from the Video class, the URL i mean

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45081/discussion-between-pmoney-and-user1919840)